# Is it possible to retrieve where a query currently is in an EXPLAIN in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have several queries which are long-running. I'd like either some way of estimating how long before the query finishes or, failing that, a way to know what step the query is on (and not just "Parsing", "Planning", etc. I'm looking for execution statistics).

I know I can check to see if a query is running by looking in `pg_stat_activity`.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE query ILIKE '%table_name%';
```

But what I'm really interested is can I get something like this:

```
Query status                                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Append  (cost=3.42..181109110.07 rows=294666 width=1113)                            
  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=3.42..63225432.03 rows=160738 width=1057)        
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3.15..20470831.91 rows=160738 width=476)   
              Join Filter: ((tbl.foo_code)::text = (other_tbl.foo_code)::text)
               ^^^^^ right now it is here
              ->  Merge Join  (cost=2.72..19913290.23 rows=160738 width=452)   
              Merge Cond: ((tbl.barnaby)::text = (support_tbl.barnaby)::text)
```

If I could get an explain of a running query, that would be great, too.

Comment: Queries do not execute one node at a time. Rather they all execute more or less simultaneously as data is based around between them.

Comment: I suspected that, but I had to ask, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the execution plan of a currently running query, but you need to install the [pg_show_plans](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_show_plans) extension for that.

There is, however, no way to see where in the execution of a plan you are currently stuck. The only way to figure that out is to connect to the backend process with a debugger and look at the stack trace. That requires thorough knowledge of the PostgreSQL source code.